# Liferay 6.1 Zenlike Theme

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, breadcrumbs, liferay-velocity, liferay-theme

I am using Liferay 6.1 CE bundled with tomcat, I deployed the Zenlike Theme (http://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Plugins/6.1.0%20GA1/zenlike-theme-6.1.0.1-ce-ga1-20120106155615760.war/download)  to use it in my portal.

My problems are:

1) I can't add the breadcurmbs navigation like in the classic theme.

2) When I add a child page it doesn't be shown in the navigation menu.

3)also I wanna change the style and css modification to the current page (where the user is navigating) to make it scroling (with a style different to others and which still exist until I click on it)

Answer (score 1):

1) Is caused by the following css in the main.css

```
#breadcrumbs {
    display: none;
}
```

2) The menu is not a dropdown menu so childpages will not shown.

3) Create a new theme that extends the zen-theme

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-liferay-them-7

[Jump to point 9 if you already made a theme before]

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I couldn't modify the zenlike theme without creting a new theme, just importing the existing zenlike theme and modify it ?

Comment: Instead of using theme inheretance you can also create a new theme. then copy the CSS,JS,images,templates folders under your _diffs folder (assuming your using ant)